# Error on create user on Odoo 14 Enterprise

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

as the title says i have a problem on create user on Odoo 14 Enterprise. On create partner the error doesnt show, only on create user.

Console Error:

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 684, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 360, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 913, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 532, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1389, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1381, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 394, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model_create(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_model_create
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-296>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 323, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/website_slides/models/res_users.py", line 13, in create
    user = super(Users, self).create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-198>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 344, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/digest/models/res_users.py", line 12, in create
    users = super(ResUsers, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-165>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/note/models/res_users.py", line 17, in create
    users = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-157>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/gamification/models/res_users.py", line 44, in create
    res = super(Users, self).create(values_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-146>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/auth_signup/models/res_users.py", line 241, in create
    users = super(ResUsers, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-144>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/mail/models/res_users.py", line 82, in create
    users = super(Users, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-120>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 326, in _model_create_single
    return self.browse().concat(*(create(self, vals) for vals in arg))
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 326, in <genexpr>
    return self.browse().concat(*(create(self, vals) for vals in arg))
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/generic_security_restriction/models/res_users.py", line 17, in create
    return super(ResUsers, self).create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-107>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 344, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py", line 1321, in create
    users = super(UsersView, self).create(new_vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-105>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py", line 1078, in create
    return super(UsersImplied, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-99>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py", line 543, in create
    users = super(Users, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-65>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_fields.py", line 534, in create
    recs = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3861, in create
    parents = self.env[model_name].create([
  File "<decorator-gen-257>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/base_vat/models/res_partner.py", line 554, in create
    return super(ResPartner, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-210>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/account/models/partner.py", line 493, in create
    return super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-185>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/partner_autocomplete/models/res_partner.py", line 183, in create
    partners = super(ResPartner, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-95>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/res_partner.py", line 569, in create
    partners = super(Partner, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-138>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 264, in create
    threads = super(MailThread, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-241>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/website/models/mixins.py", line 169, in create
    records = super(WebsitePublishedMixin, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-65>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_fields.py", line 534, in create
    recs = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in create
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3900, in create
    record._update_cache(vals)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 5153, in _update_cache
    cache.set(self, field, field.convert_to_cache(value, self, validate))
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 2416, in convert_to_cache
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 316, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Wrong value for res.partner.company_type: '0'
```

I have upgrade the base module, i have disable automated actions, search on modules for something relevent but nothing.

Do have any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have custom selection field company_type in company model. You need to fill this field.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, i check it and it doesnt have .... Any other idea?

Comment: How do you create the user? By RPC call or just on the frontend?

Comment: i go Settings -> Users -> Create (add data Name etc.) and on Save i get the error i post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the previous Odoo dev assign a default value on `company_type` on `User-defined Defaults` Menu.